# Change the resource used to render each item in a ResourceCollection

Tags: laravel

I have a model `App\Invoice.php` and an API resource `App\Http\Resources\Invoice.php` to transform it when sending it as JSON data.

The `Resources\Invoice.php` implementation of `toArray()`:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'invoice_number' => $this->invoice_number,
            'invoice_date' => $this->invoice_date,
            ...  
            // many more fields
        ];
    }
```

I also have a resource collection `App\Http\Resources\InvoiceCollection.php` to send back a list of Invoices as an array of JSON objects.

Without changing the default implementation of the resource collection it uses the `Resources\Invoice` class to transform each of the `Invoice` objects added to the array.

`Resources\InvoiceCollection` implementtation:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);
    }
```

I now need to send back a collection of invoices but with fewer fields than the default `Resources\Invoice.php` class implements. I could use the same resource but I don't like transmitting more data than I need to.

So I've created a new resource called `InvoiceSummary.php` and its `toArray()` implementation is has only a few fields:

```
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'invoice_number' => $this->invoice_number,
            'invoice_date' => $this->invoice_date,
            'issuer_name' => $this->issuer->name,
            'recipient_name' => $this->recipient->name,
            'invoice_total' => $this->totalAmount()
        ];
    }
```

How do I change the `Resource\InvoiceCollection` class to use this new summary resource rather than the original `Invoice` resource?

One way I thought of is to name the summary resource as `Invoice.php` (and rename the resource which returns the full `Invoice` details to something like `InvoiceComplete`) so it is automatically picked up and used by the collection, but I would like to learn how to change the collection and specify which resource is used.

Comment: I think you can override the collections constructor and pass the classname of your `InvoiceSummary` in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) you can delcare a property on your resource collection called `$collects` which can be assigned a class name.

> Customizing The Underlying Resource Class
>   Typically, the $this->collection property of a resource collection is automatically populated with the result of mapping each item of the collection to its singular resource class. The singular resource class is assumed to be the collection's class name without the trailing Collection string.
>
> For example, UserCollection will attempt to map the given user instances into the User resource. To customize this behavior, you may override the $collects property of your resource collection:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection;

class UserCollection extends ResourceCollection
{
    /**
     * The resource that this resource collects.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $collects = 'App\Http\Resources\Member';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I managed to miss that in the documentation, but it's working now.